# Dotnetnuke.install.config documentation

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am looking to create a custom build of DotNetNuke (vr. 7.4.2). Trying to configure the configuration file (Dotnetnuke.install.config.resources) for the installation in order to fit my custom build seems to be puzzle. There are some specific tags by default in this file and my research on-line gave me some more tags but I could not find something like an official documentation. Something that will give me all the available tags at least an example for each one (if not a list with the all available values of the tags). Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is not detailed documentation out there at this time on all of the options that are available. Most of the default configuration items are values though that you can find in the database in portal settings or host settings from an installation that you have configured.

My past experience has been to create an install and configure it how I want first. This way I have the ability to confirm a few of the values along the way. If you have a more specific question or area of concern we might be able to help.

Comment: Yes, I think that they should add something in their new documentation. We are re-deploy from scratch in each build, so all of our configs are inserted during installation. Missing documentation for the actual installation make it really hard to make any changes.

Comment: I agree, if you would like feel free to start some posting out on the Wiki, I'll dig through some of my notes and see if I can find some stuff as well to add into the mix.